# Transformation of Orthonormal Bases

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, orthonormal

Suppose that $u_1, . . . , u_n$ and $v_1, . . . , v_n$ are orthonormal bases for $\Bbb{R}^n$. Construct the matrix A that transforms each $u_i$ into $v_i$ to give $Av_1 = u_1, . . . Av_n = u_n$.

Comment: Would the answer just be an identity matrix A of dimension n?

Answer (score 1):

Let $U$ and $V$ be two square matrices whose column vectors are
$u_1,u_2,\ldots,u_n$ and $v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_n$, respectively. Then
$$AV=U\quad\Longrightarrow\quad A=AVV^\top=UV^\top.$$
**Remark:** We already know $V^\top V=I_n$, so there is a fact that $VV^\top=I_n$.

Answer (score 0):

Because the bases are orthonormal, then
$$
          Ax = (x,v_1)u_1+(x,v_2)u_2+\cdots+(x,v_n)u_n
$$
maps $v_j$ to $u_j$ for $1 \le j \le n$. (I am using $(\cdot,\cdot)$ to denote the Euclidean inner product on $\mathbb{R}^n$.) Let $u_{j,1}, u_{j,2},\cdots,u_{j,n}$ be the components of $u_j$. Similarly for $v_j$. Then
\begin{align}
   Ax & = (x,v_1)\left[\begin{array}{c}
              u_{1,1} \\ u_{1,2} \\ \vdots \\ u_{1,n}
            \end{array}\right]+
      (x,v_2)\left[\begin{array}{c}
              u_{2,1} \\ u_{2,2} \\ \vdots \\ u_{2,n}
            \end{array}\right]+
        \cdots+
           (x,v_n)\left[\begin{array}{c}
              u_{n,1} \\ u_{n,2} \\ \vdots \\ u_{n,n}
            \end{array}\right] \\
      & = \left[\begin{array}{cccc}
          u_{1,1} & u_{2,1} & \cdots & u_{n,1} \\
          u_{1,2} & u_{2,2} & \cdots & u_{n,2} \\
           \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
          u_{1,n} & u_{2,n} & \cdots & u_{n,n}
         \end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{c}(x,v_1) \\ (x,v_2) \\ \vdots \\ (x,v_n)\end{array}\right] \\
    & = 
   \left[\begin{array}{cccc}
          u_{1,1} & u_{2,1} & \cdots & u_{n,1} \\
          u_{1,2} & u_{2,2} & \cdots & u_{n,2} \\
           \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
          u_{1,n} & u_{2,n} & \cdots & u_{n,n}
         \end{array}\right]
        \left[\begin{array}{cccc}v_{1,1} & v_{1,2} & \cdots & v_{1,n} \\
            v_{2,1} & v_{2,2} & \cdots & v_{2,n} \\
             \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
            v_{n,1} & v_{n,2} & \cdots & v_{n,n}
              \end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{c}x_1 \\ x_2 \\ \vdots \\ x_n\end{array}\right]
\end{align}